# call jquery function in angular.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to use this menu in my angular app
http://tympanus.net/Development/ResponsiveMultiLevelMenu/
But i don't now how to call jquery script in angular i have search around but not anything working for me. i have call script in directive such like this

```
appDirectives.directive('menu-directive', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        link: function ($scope, $elem, attrs) {
        $( '#dl-menu' ).dlmenu();
    }
    };
});
```

But not working for me.

Original script is this

```
<script>
            $(function() {
                $( '#dl-menu' ).dlmenu();
            });
        </script>
```

Any help please.

Comment: How is it not working? Is there an error in the console?

Comment: There are no error. but script also not working.

Comment: it may help others if you update your question with what you know now so they dont have to read through tons of comments. You now have your directive working after changing its name and referencing it properly thanks to `Carlos Mayo`. The issue is now related to the `dlmenu` plugin itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute a jQuery function in the element that have the directive you must do:

```
link: function ($scope, $elem, attrs) {
   $elem.dlmenu();
}
```

**EDIT:** I've edited the code

Comment: Any error in the console? Can you provide a JSFiddle to test the code? As @Jorge said, maybe you need to load the jquery because angularjs has a lite jquery version if you not has loaded jquery full version previously.

Comment: <script src="vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script> here is jquery which is using.

Comment: Here where i want to call
<menu-directive>
     <div id="dl-menu" class="dl-menuwrapper">
      <button class="dl-trigger">Open Menu</button>
      <ul class="dl-menu">
Here is directive inwhich i am calling script function
appDirectives.directive('menu-directive', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        link: function ($scope, $elem, attrs) {
        $elem.dlmenu();
    }
    };
});

Comment: Change appDirectives.directive('menu-directive' to appDirectives.directive('menuDirective' as @ste2425 said

Comment: <menuDirective>
     <div id="dl-menu" class="dl-menuwrapper">
      <button class="dl-trigger">Open Menu</button>
      <ul class="dl-menu">
       <li></li>
</ul>
</div>
 </menuDirective>

Comment: appDirectives.directive('menuDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        link: function ($scope, $elem, attrs) {
        $elem.dlmenu();
    }
    };
});

Comment: <menu-directive> <div id="dl-menu" class="dl-menuwrapper"> <button class="dl-trigger">Open Menu</button> <ul class="dl-menu"> <li></li> </ul> </div> </menu-directive> and appDirectives.directive('menuDirective', function() { return { restrict: 'EA', link: function ($scope, $elem, attrs) { $elem.children('#dl-menu').dlmenu(); } }; })

Comment: Not working here is link of app
http://1stfold.com/taskbox/dev/POS/angular/#/app/scan/
in bottom of orange section you can see neavigation button. it should be open some thing like this http://tympanus.net/Development/ResponsiveMultiLevelMenu/

Comment: Change <menudirective> to <menu-directive> in the template

Comment: changed but no effect.

Comment: I still see in your code the <menudirective> tag. You must use <menu-directive> tag, and in your directive declaration you must use directive('menuDirective') as @ste2425 has detailed

Comment: but by doing this directive name will be different in template and in directive. however i used but no given error.

Comment: But now the error is from dlmenu plugin and Modernizr (TypeError: Cannot read property 'prefixed' of undefined). Please check you have successfully loaded the plugin and all this dependecies scripts

Comment: And read this manual https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive where explain how Angular normalize the tags and attributes name

Comment: everything else working fine when i add directive name it give error however when i add same name there are no error.

Comment: When you set the same name there is no error because Angular don't execute this code beacuse has incorrect name

Comment: As carlos Mayo said. It give the error now because angular has actually run the directive. However you have another issue with your jquery plugin. Before angular never ran the directive because the name was never parsed. Also please read the docs. This is rather basic stuff regarding directives.

Comment: Error just due to this peace of code
$elem.children('#dl-menu').dlmenu();

Comment: can you suggest me any solution for this?

Comment: This is an error of the jquery plugin, please check this https://github.com/codrops/ResponsiveMultiLevelMenu/issues/10

Comment: Maybe you must load the Modernizr script before the dlmenu plugin and jquery

Comment: Ok, if your question has been resolved please consider to accept the correct answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

By default, angular uses a jquery version called jqlite, here's the documentation [enter link description here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)

Also, the $element object, is already a jquery object you should be able to manipulate the element, and find the child nodes, we need to see how your view is defined to see how you can apply your directive

Answer (score 0):

Initialize jquery plugin after angular is ready.

```
appDirectives.directive('menu-directive', function($timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    link: function ($scope, $elem, attrs) {
      $timeout(function() {
        $('#dl-menu').dlmenu();
      }, 0);
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: i have used this code but not useful for me. script not working.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Following your comments in @CarlosMayo answer and the live demo you posted in his answer : http://1stfold.com/taskbox/dev/POS/angular/#/app/scan/ You appear to be getting a little confused.

You implement your directive in `javascript` like so:

```
.directive('menuDirective')
```

NOT

```
.directive('menu-directive')
```

But you use it in your markup like

```
<menu-directive></menu-directive>
```

NOT (which you are in your demo)

```
<menuDirective></menuDirective>
```

Angular will convert the camelCase into dash seperated string for use in your markup.

---

How are you implementing your directive? I may be wrong but it think your name is formatted incorrectly so your directive is not being applied thus the link function not being called.

I believe angular uses camel case and converts it to dash seperated word.

Try the following:

```
appDirectives.directive('menuDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        link: function ($scope, $elem, attrs) {
        $elem.dlmenu();
    }
    };
});
```

Then in your view

```
<menu-directive></menu-directive>
<!--or-->
<div menu-directive></dive>
```

see fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mazjfjv4/1/

Comment: No not working i have applied as you said but not calling script.

Comment: appDirectives.directive('menu-directive', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        link: function ($scope, $elem, attrs) {
        $elem.dlmenu();
    }
    };
});

Comment: @FarrukahZaman You haven't implemented like i said sorry. You put `.directive('menu-directive')` i said `.directive('menuDirective')`. Thats how angular maps its directive names.

Comment: .directive('menuDirective'
<menuDirective>

Comment: Use this but no effect